# Convenient way to interact between cells and view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have UITableView controller with different cells, each one is different subclass of UITableView cell.

Some of this cells have UIControl elements, such as UITextField. The problem is, its value "hidden" inside cell, so, basically i want to extract this value from it.

I could use NSNotification/Delegate/Singleton/NSUserDefaults for it, by i guess that is not the best approach.

Is there any easy way to deal with such situation and get value that is inside UItableView cell?

Comment: As always, according to the (M)odel(V)iew(C)controller pattern the recommended way is to mirror the values in appropriate properties in the data source array and get the data from there.

Comment: "Convenient way" is a very broad / ambiguous / opinion based request. There are many ways to achieve this, but all depends on your use case. For example, if I was building a form, I might find it convenient to have all the cells conform to a protocol and fire back each piece of data to the VC (but you seem to not based on your question). I might find it convenient to have the subclasses store the data somewhere when the user losses focus on an element. You should research this yourself and find what you find "Convenient"

Comment: @vadian how exactly should i do that?

Comment: Create a custom class (to get reference semantics) with the properties you need and update the properties each time the user changes the value in the cell. There are delegate methods / notifications to monitor text fields and `IBOutlet` / target-action methods to monitor buttons, switches etc. For example In a custom cell you can pass the model object in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` to be able to update the model directly. Since you have always the index path it's much more efficient to retrieve the data from the model rather than from the view.